# Load UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Eu tenho um UIViewController com o Background preto onde seria minha UIViewController principal (onde fica o menu e etc) e eu faço isso:

```
CredenciaisViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];    
[_viewContainer addSubview:obj.view];
    _viewContainer.alpha = 1;
```

A CredenciaisViewController tem o background vermelho e eu carrego ela em um UIView que está na minha UIViewController principal, mas quando ela se carrega dentro da view ela fica metade branca e os UiButtons quando estão na parte branca não funcionam.

Por que isso acontece?
E como faço para resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode adicionar um `UIViewController` como *subview* de outra `UIView`. Para esse propósito, existe o [Custom Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Daí então você pode adicionar através do método [addChildViewController:childController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:) em seu `UIContainerView` e não `UIView` como no seu exemplo.

No *interface builder* você pode localizar ele, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De forma dinâmica, faça algo assim na ação do seu `UIButton`:

```
- (IBAction)mostrarCredenciais:(id)sender {
    CredenciaisViewController *credenciaisView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];

    [self addChildViewController:credenciaisView];
    [credenciaisView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    credenciaisView.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:credenciaisView.view];
}
```

Com isso você não precisa fazer então a conexão no *storyboard* do container com o `UIViewController`. Basta ligar o `IBOutlet` (que é um `UIView` normal), que no meu exemplo é o `containerView`.

Comment: Quando eu arrasto o ContainerView para a tela, ele cria uma ligação com outra UIViewController, eu preciso dessa ligação ou consigo chamar dinamicamente a UIViewController que quero?

Comment: Inseri o Container View na minha UIViewController que tem o Menu.
E liguei ela no:
@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIView *viewContainer;
Quando clica no menu tentei carregado o conteúdo de 2 formas.
Primeira forma:
        CredenciaisViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];
        [_viewContainer addSubview:obj.view];
Segunda Forma:
CredenciaisViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];
        [self addChildViewController:obj];

Mas não carregou o conteúdo em nenhuma das duas formas.

Comment: Por que não fazer a conexão no próprio *storyboard* já que todos os elementos que você precisa estão lá?

Comment: Paulo, realmente é melhor, fiz no storyboard e carregou, porém ele carrega assim que rodo o projeto e não quando eu clico no botão, como faço para ele não abrir de cara?
Desculpa, estou começando com ios!

Comment: Ok, neste caso realmente tem que ser algo dinâmico. Editei minha resposta, veja se você consegue reproduzir.

Comment: Paulo, consegui reproduzir sim e carregou certinho o conteúdo, porém quando eu clico na tela (fora de qualquer botão) com o conteúdo carregado ele pisca a tela e carrega novamente o conteúdo, duplicando ele. Por que?

Comment: Eu consegui parar de duplicar os conteúdos, eu fiz isso:
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

E parou de duplicar quando eu clico no background da tela onde não tem botão, porém quando clico na tela fora de qualquer botão dá uma piscada, só gostaria de tirar isso, o restante está perfeito.

Comment: Esse é um comportamento estranho que não encontrei aqui, veja o [exemplo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1o0NIBAU7UjejV2Nm5aUjR4TXM/view?usp=sharing) bem simples que fiz. Em nenhum momento teve esse comportamento de piscar.